# New tag [julius-speech] needed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

There is currently a tag [julius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julius) which refers to [a part of the Yesod application](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates).

For those of us more accustomed to associate Julius with [the speech recognition engine](https://github.com/julius-speech/julius), it might be useful to have a separate tag such as "julius-speech" to separate out the two streams. Or is it customary in Stack Overflow to have tags doing double duty?

Comment: Tags should refer to one thing only, if not we'll bring them up on meta as [tag:tag-disambiguation] requests. There are only 10 questions tagged [tag:julius] right now, maybe we should rename that tag to something more specific as well.

Comment: FWIW I created [tag:julius-speech]. Feel free to suggest a description/wiki for it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not customary to have tags meaning two completely different things. We disambiguate them. In this case I retagged the questions with:

- [yesod-julius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yesod-julius) (x6) for the ones related to the Yesod application. I added [julius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julius) as a synonym to this, and moved over the tag wiki.
- [julius-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julius-speech) (x8) for the ones related to the Julius Speech. 4 of them were already retagged, after the tag was created by approxiblue.